# js import/export and chrome/opera/firefox extensions. State of things in 2020

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, chromium, es6-modules

I'm thinking on migrating my higly modular browser extension to working with *es6 import/export* thing...

**In short the question is this:**

> Please, state the main problem (one is enough) as of 2020 faced by someone using import/export expressions
> while making chromium extension for chrome/firefox/opera etc. Thanks.

**In long the question is this:**

Untill now I was able to do without those fancy hipster ES6 things by doing this:

1. each module in separet file
2. each module is wrapped in (function() { module code })();
3. I use Gulp to concatenate all the modules into single bundle.js which is being deployed as chromium extension.

I was toying with js import/export but came about some stackexchange post of problems and people inventing hacks to make them work on content script side...

My project is too big and evolving. So for me it's hard before venturing into ES6-modules to test all the possible edge cases. And the stackoverflow has some discussions of the problems but dating 2018 only.

Can some knowledgeable person plainly state all the problems he has faced in using import/export expressions in **2020** while making chromium extension for chrome/firefox/opera etc. The year is ending and I feel it's a good time to ask such a question.
Thanks.

Comment: It's very simple: use ES modules in your *source* code then build into a bundle so the production code is the same standard js that doesn't need import hacks.

Comment: Yes, I though about it. But why use imports at all if you bundle them all together anyway? I mean... it just defeats the point of the import/export syntax, right?

Comment: ES modules have a better/richer IDE support.

Comment: "*Please list all XY that you can think of*" is not a useful question format, it is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @coobit What do you think is the point of modularisation? No, bundling modules does not defeat any of the benefits for developers.

Comment: Yes, I agree, maybe I can rephrase the question better: Is it fully sopported or are ther restrictions still? I've changed the question to a more polite form.

Comment: @Bergi mmm I then don't understand the point of modularization...  Can you explain (i'm serious) in the context of chrome extension. thanks.

Comment: @coobit [Modularisation in the context of programming in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) benefits the developer by imposing (or allowing to define) a structure on smaller components. Same reason we use functions with local scopes or multiple files instead of one.

Comment: @ Bergi , Yeah, but I do modules using IIFE (function(){
    //module
})();
So I have benefits of modules, but I was thinking using es6 modules since they are "cleaner". But If I have to bundle everything togethere in any case why bother with es6? Perhaps I just don't understand your comment. Sorry.